# Are Akka .conf dispatcher configuration working?

Tags: configuration, akka, dispatcher

I'm using Akka 2.2-RC1 and I'm not able to get Akka to load dispatcher configuration from application.conf:

```
my-dispatcher {
  type = PinnedDispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
}

akka.actor.deployment {
  /test {
    dispatcher = my-dispatcher
  }
}
```

When instantiated from code like

```
 val test = system.actorOf(Props[Test], "test")
```

by logs it is still using `akka.actor.default-dispatcher`.

When I'm adding `.withDispatcher("my-dispatcher")` to Props all is working properly and `my-dispatcher` is used. But I do not like idea of adding `.withDispatcher(...)` to all my actors...

Do anyone know where could be a problem? I was thinking that actor path may be wrong, but apllication.conf routing configuration works properly (with exception of custom routee dispatcher, again).

---

After some testing I've found that this effect is caused by use of `RemoteActorRefProvider`. As soon as I disabled it and changed to default

```
akka.actor.provider = "akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider"
```

dispatchers were configuring from config properly.

I guess with remoting enabled Akka looks elsewhere for configuration of actor dispatchers or maybe remote refs have different logical paths?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked fine for me on the same version of akka that you were using.  My config:

```
test{
  my-dispatcher {
    type = PinnedDispatcher
    executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  }

  akka.actor.deployment {
    /test-actor {
      dispatcher = my-dispatcher
    }
  }
}
```

My code:

```
object ActorTest{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
    val system = ActorSystem("test", conf.getConfig("test"))
    val ref = system.actorOf(Props[TestActor], "test-actor")
  }
}

class TestActor extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

I used jconsole and shows that the pinned dispatcher was listed under the Threads tab

Comment: Thanks for info, with "test" sub-config it really works. But as soon as I move dispatcher and deployment configuration back to 'root' -- it stops working.

Comment: I've found that problem is caused by `akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider` -- when disabled all is working properly.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, would you mind opening a ticket at our assembla tracker? Thanks!

Comment: @Seigert, will you take care of opening the bug as you are the one who found it?

Comment: Bug report is here: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/3445#/activity/ticket: